# SQL set all rows in column as multiples of other column

Tags: sql, for-loop, variables, sql-update, mariadb

I need to set all column `exp_perkPoints` in all rows of table users, as a multiple of respective value of column `exp_level`.

I created this code, for all 302 rows in my table, however I get this error: #1064 - Something is wrong in your syntax next to 'DECLARE 
   a number(3)' in line 1

```sql
DECLARE 
   a number(3); 
   @b number(3);
BEGIN 
   FOR a in 1 .. 302 LOOP 
    SELECT @b = `exp_level`
        FROM `users`
        WHERE `userid` = a; 
    UPDATE `users` SET `exp_perkPoints`=@b*2;
  END LOOP; 
END; 
/
```

My expected result is for each user's exp_perkPoints to be set as 2*exp_level.

Edit:
I also tried with the following mariadb syntax, with no success:

```sql
BEGIN
  DECLARE v1 INT DEFAULT 302;
  DECLARE v2 INT DEFAULT 0;

  WHILE v1 > 0 DO
    SELECT exp_level INTO v2
    FROM users
    WHERE userid = v1;
    UPDATE users
    SET exp_perkPoints = v2 * 2
    WHERE userid = v1;
    SET v1 = v1 - 1;
  END WHILE;
END
```

Sample data:

Table: users

Columns: userid, exp_level, exp_perkPoints

1 | 12 | empty

2 | 1 | empty

etc

Desired result:
For userid equal to 1 take his exp_level, set his exp_perkPoints as exp_level * 2.
Repeat for all userid's.

Comment: syntax depends on SQL Technology.  But your variables should have @ in front of them, your first variable of a  does not.

Comment: mariadb 10.1.26

Comment: via phpmyadmin cp

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Done, thanks for contribution

Comment: The _error_ is probably that this syntax applies only inside Stored Routines.  The _solution_ is as @knot22 points out.

Answer (score 1):

When working with databases, it is imperative to think in sets instead of processing rows one-by-one which is how a loop operates.  Set based solutions perform better in databases and the code is concise.

For this question, performing an update on the exp_perkPoints column in the users table looks like this:

```
update users
set exp_perkPoints = exp_level * 2;
```

Here is the result:
[image]